# Insertion at beginning in the linked list

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I am a beginner in data structure. I tried to insert a new node at the beginning of a linked list. But the node is not at all inserted. The problem arise only in the insertion at beginning. 
Please help me
Here is my code

```
public class singlylinkedlist {
link head;
static class link
{
    int data;
    link nextNode;
    link(int dat)
    {
        data=dat;
        nextNode=null;
    }
}
public static void insertbegin(link head,int x)
{
    link newnode=new link(x);
    newnode.nextNode=head;
    head=newnode;
}
static void display(link head)
{
    if(head==null) System.out.println("empty list");
    else
    {
        link temp=head;
        while(temp!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(temp.data);
            temp=temp.nextNode;
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    singlylinkedlist link=new singlylinkedlist();
    link.head=new link(2);
    insertbegin(link.head,1);
    display(link.head);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since you are recreating the wheel (not sure if this is a saying in english too...), I would guess this is an homework. So you should at least explain what is going on in that code. PS : Welcome on SO, see [ask]

Comment: You say not properly inserted, but you don't say what the problem is. Please update the post to be more specific.

Comment: Tom avoid confusion, I would rename the `link` in `singlylinkedlist link` as you've got a class and an instance with the same name.

Comment: Just a tip : you mix `static` and `non-static` context here. Using `head` in a static method would not compile.

Comment: HEY! You just changed your code from what it originally was, that was problematic, to what is should be. NEVER DO THAT! **Add** edits with proper captions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would strongly advice you to rename your classes. Java classes should always start with a capital letter (upper camel case). And variables and methods should always be lower camel case (exception: static final variables are often all-caps).

Now to your question: Your error lies in following: inside your methods, if you assign a new value to the `head` variable that is given to the method, that change only affects the variable `head` that is given to the method (only in the methods scope). If you want to change the actual `head` variable, you need to assign the new value directly to the classes `head` variable.

Depending on your use-case, there are 3 solutions:

1. You need multiple instances of your LinkedList implementation:

   - Change the methods `insertBegin` and `display` to be non-static.
   - Remove the first parameter of the methods, as they can now access the variable `head` of the class
2. You only need one instance of your LinkedList implementation (not really a good solution):

   - Make your head variable inside the class `static`
   - Remove the first parameter of the methods, as they can now access the variable `head` of the class
3. You want to keep your static/non-static pattern for the variables/methods (for whatever reason):

   - change the behaviour of the `head` variable: It now never stores actual data, but instead stores the actual head (with data) as its `nextNode` variable.
   - `display` now always reads beginning from `head.nextValue`
   - `insertBegin` now doesn't have to overwrite the actual head variable. it only has to set its `nextNode` variable to the new head

---

If you want, I can give you an example for one of those cases. I just didn't want to write them all out and let you figure out stuff yourself.

---

If you want to improve your Java skills, i would also suggest you to look into the various visibility options for variables and methods (private, protected, public, default)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of errors. This is just not the way one would write a linked list. See [@MichaelRitter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7441378/michael-ritter)'s answer and correct them.

Make all functions in `singlylinkedlist` class non static, move the `link` class outside the `singlylinkedlist` class and write the `main()` method in another class outside the `singlylinkedlist` class.

As far as your `insertbegin()` method is concerned, you firstly need to make it non-static. Also, you need to accept only the integer value in the function's parameter that you want to insert in the beginning; taking the head node of a linked list is of no use here. Further, you need to check whether the head node of the linked list is `null` before doing anything, otherwise you'll get a `NullPointerException`.

Here's a working version of the `insertbegin()` method of the `singlylinkedlist` class:

```
public void insertbegin(int x){
    link temp = new link(x);
    if(head == null)
        head = temp;
    else{
        link ts = head;
        head = temp;
        head.nextNode = ts;
    }
}
```

If you want to insert `1` in the beginning of the singlylinkedlist called `link`, you can call the `insertbegin()` function as:

```
link.insertbegin(1);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: the inner class is actually fine. i would make it private tho (no1 outside of the linkedlist class should be able to ever see the nodes